# Drawing a commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

There several codes for commutative diagrams, but I could not find any code for the following diagram:
[image: Triangle Commutative diagram]

Comment: try searching using the following, for example, commutative diagrams site:tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
L \arrow[dd, "\forall \delta"'] \arrow[rr, "\varepsilon"] &  & U(L) \arrow[lldd, "\exists ! f"] \\
 &  &  \\
D &  & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than doubling rows and columns, I'd enlarge the separation with `column sep` and `row sep`.

Answer (score 10):

with slightly different code syntax as is in nice [Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano) answer:-)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
    L
    \arrow{r}{\varepsilon}  
    \arrow[swap]{d}{\forall\delta}           
&
    U(L)
    \arrow{dl}{\exists ! f}   \\     
%
    D
&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is different and better of mine answer +1. Happy easter. I am scarce as a user.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you. regarding `tikz-cd` i'm in learn phase about how to place labels to arrows :-) . from your answer i sow new possibility. happy easter to you to! (i already give + 1 to your answer ;-) )